# add where condition in whereHas based on the parent table's column value in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$productList = Product::where(
                function ($query) {
                    $query->where('is_status', 1);
                }
            )
                ->whereNull('errors')
                ->with(['user'])
                ->whereHas(
                    'user',
                    function ($query) {
                        $query->where('is_authenticated', 1);
                        $query->whereNotNull('username');
                        $query->whereNotNull('password');
                    }
                )
                ->get()
                ->take(10);
```

Here what I want is I want to add `$query->whereNotNull('balance');` below the `$query->whereNotNull('password');` if the that correspondence product price is more than 500. please see what I want to produce

```
$productList = Product::where(
                    function ($query) {
                        $query->where('is_status', 1);
                    }
                )
                    ->whereNull('errors')
                    ->with(['user'])
                    ->whereHas(
                        'user',
                        function ($query) {
                            $query->where('is_authenticated', 1);
                            $query->whereNotNull('username');
                            $query->whereNotNull('password');
                            if({PRICE_OF_PRODUCT} > 500) {
                              $query->whereNotNull('balance');
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    ->get()
                    ->take(10);
```

Comment: from where you get this PRICE_OF_PRODUCT

Comment: @GauravGupta, yes that's the confusion what I mean that  PRICE_OF_PRODUCT should be the Product table's column value like in raw query ->  product. price > 500 than where user.balance IS NOT NULL

Comment: this is not possible what your asking.
if you think it's possible to make a raw query I'll convert it to DB:builder method

Comment: Yes @GauravGupta, can you please share DB: builder method to produce same output

Comment: what I am saying is provide me a raw query and I'll convert it for you if your unable to do so

Comment: Okay, I will try and share it with you if I stopped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207347/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-ronak-solanki).